# Why SELECT COUNT(*) queries trigger SQL Commit

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring-Boot 2.7 RestController with an API:

```
// controller layer
@GetMapping(path = "/smth")
public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> findSomething(@RequestParam String name) {
    return smthService.findByName(name);
}

// service layer
public SomeDto findByName(String name) {
   int countSomeStuff = myTableRepository.countStuff(name); // count query
   SomeOtherDto someOtherDto = myTableRepository.findSomeOtherData(name); // select query
   return new SomeDto(countSomeStuff, someOtherDto);
}

// repository layer
public interface MyTableRepository extends CrudRepository<MyTable, Long> {
    
    @Query("SELECT COUNT(m) FROM MyTable m WHERE m.name =:name")
    int countStuff(String name);

    @Query("SELECT someOtherData...")
    SomeOtherDto findSomeOtherData(String name);
}
```

Database communication is handled by `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` without any additional settings.

**The problem:**

Dynatrace analysis of `findSomething` API call shows 3 SQL queries instead of 2, one of which is `SQL Commit`.
[image]

**The question:**

Why `select count()` triggers `sql commit`? Why transaction is needed for select count queries?

Is it because `select count` is supposed to account for possibility of another transaction to alter the contents of a table during query execution?

And can `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` cause a lock?

**Addition:**

If there're no `select count()` queries, then there are no `sql commit` queries in Dynatrace.

Answer (score 1):

In a Spring Boot application using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, methods in a repository interface are transactional by default. For example, they are wrapped within a transaction, and for transaction management, Spring uses AOP proxies that create a transaction before the method execution and commit it after the method execution if no exceptions are thrown.

In this case we can prevent that by using the `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public SomeDto findByName(String name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Right. But somehow, Dynatrace does not show `SQL Commit` queries if there are no `select count()` queries. I agree with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`. But the question is WHY `sql commit` is triggered only when `count` queries are present?

Comment: there are multiple points that could be the cause for the Dynatrace not showing the queries, for example, implicit vs explicit transaction, database locks and isolation levels, flush behavior